# Deriving gluon propagator in axial gauge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-chromodynamics, propagator, gauge

I am currently checking my work against an answer and I understand most of it except I am having difficulty understanding the signs in a particular part. The question is as follows:

> (a) Derive the gluon propagator for $\mathcal{L}_{\text {fix }}=-\frac{1}{2 \xi}\left(n^\mu A_\mu^a\right)^2$ :
> $$
> G^{A_\mu^a A_\nu^b}(p)=\frac{-\mathrm{i} \delta^{a b}}{p^2+\mathrm{i} \epsilon}\left(g_{\mu \nu}-\frac{p_\mu n_\nu+p_\nu n_\mu}{(p \cdot n)}+\frac{\left(n^2+\xi p^2\right) p_\mu p_\nu}{(p \cdot n)^2}\right) .
> $$

I first collected all the terms which are bilinear in A:
$$
\begin{aligned}
i \mathcal{L}= & -\frac{i}{4}\left(\partial_\mu A_\nu ^a \partial^\mu A^{a, \nu}-\partial_\mu A_v^a \partial^v A^{a, \mu}-\partial_v A_\mu^a \partial^\mu A^{a, {\nu}}+\partial_v A_\mu^a \partial^\mu A^{a_1 \nu}\right) \\
& -\frac{i}{2 \xi} n^\mu n^v A_\mu^a A_v^a+\ldots\\
& = -\frac{i}{2}\left[\partial_\mu A_\nu^a \partial^\mu A^{a, \nu}-\partial_\mu A_\nu^a \partial^\nu A^{a, \mu}\right] -\frac{i}{2 \xi} n^\mu n^v A_\mu^a A_v^a+\ldots\\
\end{aligned}$$

But the answer then states:

> We would like to compute $\Gamma^{(0)}[\{\Phi\}]=i \int d^4 x \mathcal{L}(\{\Phi(x)\})$, using integration by parts and assuming surface terms vanish:
> $$
> \int d^4 x \partial_\mu \Phi \partial^\mu \Phi=-\int d^4 x \Phi \partial^2 \Phi+\underbrace{\int d^4 x \partial_\mu\left(\Phi \partial^\mu \Phi\right)}_{=0 \text { (surface term) }}
> $$
> we may write
> $$
> i \mathcal{L} =\frac{i}{2} A_\mu^a\left(g^{\mu v} \partial^2-\partial^\mu \partial^v-\frac{1}{\xi} n^\mu n^v\right) A_v^a+\ldots \text { (including surface terms) }
> $$

My confusion lies with the sign of the terms. I tried applying the result of the integration by parts to $[\partial_\mu A_\nu^a \partial^\mu A^{a, \nu}]$ to get:

$$
\frac{i}{2} A_\nu^a \partial^2 A^{a, \nu}+\frac{i}{2} \partial_\mu A_\nu^a \partial^\nu A^{a, \mu}
$$
which I believe would correspond to the first two terms $(g^{\mu v} \partial^2-\partial^\mu \partial^v- \ldots)$ but the terms I got are both positive. Not sure where I have went wrong but if someone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: $\int d^4x \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi= \int d^4 x [\partial_\mu (\phi \partial^\mu \phi) - \phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi ]=\int d \sigma_\mu (\phi \partial^\mu \phi) - \int d^4 x \phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi$. Thus, neglecting the surface term, you have $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi \to -\phi \partial^2 \phi$. Analogously, $\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu \to - A_\nu \partial^2 A^\nu$ and $\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu \to -A_\nu \partial_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Sign mistake during the calculation, silly mistake on my part